# Cocoa vs Carbon

Tags: cocoa

What would be the Cocoa equivalent for this code?

```
#include <Carbon/Carbon.h>
void check_apple_events() {
    printf("check_apple_events\n");
    RgnHandle cursorRgn = NULL; 
    Boolean gotEvent=TRUE; 
    EventRecord event; 
    while (gotEvent) { 
        gotEvent = WaitNextEvent(everyEvent, &event, 0L, cursorRgn); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by reading the [How Cocoa Applications Handle Apple Events](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptableCocoaApplications/SApps_handle_AEs/SAppsHandleAEs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001239-BBCBCIJE) portion of the Cocoa Scripting Guide. Then read the rest of it and ask a more focused question.